# Is there a strictly non-deterministic one-counter language whose complement is one-counter?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, closure-properties, pushdown-automata

Let 
$A= \{L \mid L \;\text{is one-counter and \(\bar{L}\) is also one-counter} \}$

Clearly, $\text{Deterministic one-counter} \subseteq A$

Is it the case that $ A = \text{Deterministic one-counter}$?

I know that for context-free languages the analogue is not the case. For example,
let $P =\{ ww^r\}$.
Then both $P$ and $\bar{P}$ are context-free but $P$ is not deterministic.
Hence $A$ defines a (strict) subset of the context-free languages.

The question is: can we construct a similar one-counter example for which the same holds?

Comment: Something like $L=\{x\in\{a,b\}^*\mid x_{\lfloor|c|/2\rfloor}=a\}$?

Comment: what is "one-counter"?

Comment: A PDA with only one kind of symbols (aside from the bottom symbol) on  its stack.

Comment: what do you mean by $x_{\lfloor|c|/2\rfloor}=a$ ?

Comment: how about this language : $L = \{ a^ib^j \mid i=j \ or\ i=2j \} $ and  $\bar{L} = \{a^ib^j \mid i \neq j \ and\ i\neq 2j\}$

Comment: @emmy: How would a (nondeterministic) 1CM decide $\overline{L}$?

Comment: see this [link](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10635/is-l-aibj-mid-j-neq-i-and-j-neq2i-context-free)

Comment: @emmy: Ooops, typo: I meant of course $x_{\lfloor x/2\rfloor}$ i.e. the symbol at the $\lfloor x/2\rfloor$-th position.

Comment: @frafl thanks! that's neat and simple.

Answer (score -1):

In response to Shaull's comment above :
[image]
[image]

The first one is an image of 1-counter accepting $a^ib^j$ s.t. $j<i$

The secong one is an image of 1-counter accepting $a^ib^j$ s.t. $j>i,\ j<2i$

The third one is an image of 1-counter accepting $a^ib^j$ s.t. $j>2i$

Here a/-/plus means on seeing a, irrespective of the counter value, increment the counter.
b/>1?/sub means on seeing b, if counter value is greater than 1, then decrement the counter.

nop =>  no operation

$\lambda $ => empty string

Comment: Quite a long answer which is essentially just "Because its the union of three languages, each recognizing one interval of $i$s relative to $j$".

Comment: yeah :) just wanted to prove it can be done by 1-counter automata

Comment: It's OK to elaborate a bit especially if it's a nice exercise for you, but please add a short summary. Additionally you should not use an answer to reply to a comment, but in this case this reply may become an actual answer to your question, so I think it's OK, too.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no proof here.