# Is $L= \{ a^ib^j \mid j\neq i \ and \ j\neq2i \ \} $ context free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pushdown-automata

$L = \{ a^ib^j \mid j\neq i \ and \ j\neq2i \ \} $

Is this language a context free language?
If yes give a PDA. If no, give a proof.

The pumping lemma for context free languages doesn't seem to work here.

Let $p>1$ be the pumping length. Let the string be divided into five parts according to pumping lemma as $w = uvxyz$.

For any string of the form $a^ib^j \ s.t.$:

1. $ j\lt i-1$ choose $v=a, \ x=\epsilon, \ y=\epsilon$
2. $ j\gt 2i+1$ choose $v=\epsilon, \ x=\epsilon, \ y=b$
3. $ j = i-1$ choose $v=a, \ x=\epsilon, \ y=b$
4. $ j =  2i+1$ choose $v=a, \ x=\epsilon, \ y=b$
5. $ j\gt i,\ j\lt 2i $ choose $v=a, \ x=\epsilon, \ y=b$

Comment: Have you tried proving the opposite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is context Free.

You can see it as a union of two languages:
$L_1$ where $j>2i$ and $L_2$ which is very similar to the one of [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9831/157).

More information you can find in [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9804/157).

Comment: Isn't this close to a duplicate?

Comment: @Raphael, close yes, but sufficiently different for my taste.